# function same as lag partition by in clickouse

Tags: lag, partition, clickhouse

I need to know the frequency of order for each user. I mean difference between 2 order time for each user.
In SQL I used "Lag Partition by" but I don't know how I can calculate this in click house.
I need this data:
[image]

at first I should sort data with user_id and created_at then I need to have next order time for each user id in row. I can't use neighbor function because it can't do partition by user_id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't understand why [neighbor](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/sql-reference/functions/other-functions/#neighbor) cannot be used in your case, but it should works well:

```sql
SELECT 
    user_id,
    created,
    if(neighbor(user_id, 1, NULL) != user_id, NULL, neighbor(created, 1, NULL)) AS next_created
FROM 
(
    SELECT 
        number % 3 AS user_id,
        now() + (number * 360) AS created
    FROM numbers(11)
    ORDER BY 
        user_id ASC,
        created ASC
)

/*
┌─user_id─┬─────────────created─┬────────next_created─┐
│       0 │ 2020-10-21 16:00:21 │ 2020-10-21 16:18:21 │
│       0 │ 2020-10-21 16:18:21 │ 2020-10-21 16:36:21 │
│       0 │ 2020-10-21 16:36:21 │ 2020-10-21 16:54:21 │
│       0 │ 2020-10-21 16:54:21 │                ᴺᵁᴸᴸ │
│       1 │ 2020-10-21 16:06:21 │ 2020-10-21 16:24:21 │
│       1 │ 2020-10-21 16:24:21 │ 2020-10-21 16:42:21 │
│       1 │ 2020-10-21 16:42:21 │ 2020-10-21 17:00:21 │
│       1 │ 2020-10-21 17:00:21 │                ᴺᵁᴸᴸ │
│       2 │ 2020-10-21 16:12:21 │ 2020-10-21 16:30:21 │
│       2 │ 2020-10-21 16:30:21 │ 2020-10-21 16:48:21 │
│       2 │ 2020-10-21 16:48:21 │                ᴺᵁᴸᴸ │
└─────────┴─────────────────────┴─────────────────────┘
*/
```

Comment: neighbor is broken by design
https://gist.github.com/den-crane/54612fd083cfd92a1ead10ef0bd0f80b

Comment: @DennyCrane this behavior expected as you know. To enforce CH to 'merge' all data blocks probably can help only data aggregation, like this crazy query *select A , neighbor(A, 1)  n  from (select any(A) as A from A group by blockNumber(), rowNumberInBlock() order by A)* ;)

Answer (score 1):

`groupArray` allows to transform this

```
select 1 uid, 555 time union all select 1, 666 union all select 1, 777
┌─uid─┬─time─┐
│   1 │  555 │
│   1 │  666 │
│   1 │  777 │
└─────┴──────┘
```

to this

```
select uid, groupArray(time) dtime from 
   (select * from (select 1 uid, 555 time union all select 1, 666 union all select 1, 777) order by uid, time) 
  group by uid

┌─uid─┬─dtime─────────┐
│   1 │ [555,666,777] │
└─────┴───────────────┘
```

and

```
select uid, arrayJoin(arrayPushBack(arrayPopFront(groupArray(time)), null)) dtime from 
   (select * from (select 1 uid, 555 time union all select 1, 666 union all select 1, 777) order by uid, time) 
  group by uid
┌─uid─┬─dtime─┐
│   1 │   666 │
│   1 │   777 │
│   1 │  ᴺᵁᴸᴸ │
└─────┴───────┘


select uid, time, atime from (
  select uid, groupArray(time) as stime, arrayPushBack(arrayPopFront(stime), null) dtime from 
   (select * from (select 1 uid, 555 time union all select 1, 666 union all select 1, 777) order by uid, time) 
  group by uid )
   array join stime as time, dtime as atime
┌─uid─┬─time─┬─atime─┐
│   1 │  555 │   666 │
│   1 │  666 │   777 │
│   1 │  777 │  ᴺᵁᴸᴸ │
└─────┴──────┴───────┘
```