# Time difference when activity changes in logs

Tags: sql, datetime, clickhouse

There is table *logs* with user logs.

[image]

It is necessary to find the time of the action change (from 0 to 1) for every users. Everyone can change the action several times.

I try to use *neighbor()* for datetime, but has a strange results and it ignores user_id change.

```
SELECT user_id,
   diff_time
FROM (
    SELECT user_id,
           actions,
           datetime,
           neighbor(server_dt, -1, server_dt) as prev_time,
           dateDiff('second', prev_time, server_dt) as diff_time
    FROM logs
    WHERE actions = 1
)
```

As a result, I would like to get something like this table

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64466901/function-same-as-lag-partition-by-in-clickouse

Comment: Your sample data has only two examples of a change from 0 to 1.  Why do the desired results have three rows?